Platform Event Subscription Related Query
Can anyone please help me with this .

The event subscription is done using apex trigger.

I have a subscriber which is in Running Status and actively listening the events.

I manually suspended the subscriber and meanwhile published 5 more events.

Then resumed the subscriber.


But the trigger picked the latest ones and there is no track of the 5 events published during the downtime.
Question : Is there any way to ensure that the subscriber starts listening from where it left.
We are using apex trigger as subscriber on after insert. We need to basically keep track of lost events during system downtime .
While publish we can use EventBus.EventPublishFailureCallBack , so publish side I am good. But during subscription how to know that system was down and we have lost 4 events ?
I tried setResumeCheckPoint but it didn't help  ?
